# Table design, composite key

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with some data summary which consist of `client_id, location_id, category_id and summary` columns. Values of the three id's columns are not unique.

At the moment I have created a `composite key` from client_id, location_id, category_id using primary keys. Those three columns will uniquely identify rows.

My question is, if I still should include unique primary key for that table for example column with auto-increment id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends completely on your uses of the table. If you don't want to refer to a given row in a query (for example, having a dependent table), the separate PK is unnecessary (eg. if you always ask for statistics for a given client and a given location and a given category). However, if you do have dependent tables, you probably want a separate PK as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your composite key is the primary clustered index then I would say it's not necessary.